# find selected checkbox in a tablerow group

Tags: android, checkbox, tablelayout, tablerow

Hello i have something like this

```
TableLayout tblGrid = new TableLayout(getBaseContext());
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    EditText edtArticulo = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    EditText edtCantidad = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    EditText edtPrecio = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    EditText edtSubtotal = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    CheckBox chbSeleccion = new CheckBox(getBaseContext());
    TableRow tbrRenglon = = new TableRow(getBaseContext());

    tbrRenglon.addView(chbSeleccion, 0);
    tbrRenglon.addView(edtArticulo, 1);
    tbrRenglon.addView(edtCantidad, 2);
    tbrRenglon.addView(edtPrecio, 3);
    tbrRenglon.addView(edtSubtotal, 4);
}
tblGrid.addView(tbrRenglon);
```

my problem is i can´t find the selected checkbox in the group of tablerows

i need some help please

Comment: This code doesn't show how you go about finding the checkbox

Comment: How do you try to find checkbox? Paste the code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to each checkbox in an array outside the loop.
Then loop over the array to see which are checked